# Can't show panel from commandbutton

Tags: primefaces

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton onclick="PF('panel1').show()" value="Show Panel" type="button" />
</h:form>
```

This is the button through which I am trying to show the panel:

```
<p:panel rendered="#{carBean.show}" widgetVar="panel1">
    <h:form id="createCarForm" class="form-horizontal" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h2>Create Car Record</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</p:panel>
```

This is the panel which I am trying to show.

Comment: Any errors anywhere? What did you debug? Don't see any reason this should not work if 'rendered' NOT equals false. If it IS false, then you cannot show it with the javascript you use. Try using `visible="#{carBean.show}"` then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in `rendered="#{carBean.show}"` the 'show' is equal to false, the resulting component is not going to be in the client-side html (or serverside view for that matter). That is what rendered does. If you want the panel to initially not be visible, you should use excactly that, the `visible` attribute.

```
<p:panel visible="#{carBean.show}" widgetVar="panel1">
 ...
</p:panel>
```

You should be able to use the commandButton then as you defined it.

```
 <p:commandButton onclick="PF('panel1').show()" value="Show Panel" type="button" />
```

Comment: thanks for your response. i tried what you said and the panel is hidden initially. how can i make it visible on the command button then?

Comment: It is for me in several places. And 'not working'  is too vague. Any errors?